# Finite self-maps exist on rigid CY3s

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth projective rigid Calabi-Yau threefold.

> **Question.** Does there exist a finite map $X\to X$ of degree $>1$?

Comment: The article "Endomorphisms of smooth projective 3-folds with non-negative Kodaira dimension"
Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci. 38 (2002), no. 1, 33–92 by Y. Fujimoto probably contains the answer to your question.

Comment: Welcome @smprcy. Is a CY threefold simply connected with trivial canonical bundle with your definitions? If so, you can argue as follows:  your finite map will be etale (by Riemann-Hurwitz) and thus trivial by simple-connectedness.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Could you explain the argument in more detail? Don't some K3s have non-trivial self-isogenies?

Comment: @nrlof: no. They have "self-rational maps", but not everywhere defined. Indeed any finite map between smooth projective varieties with trivial canonical bundle must be étale.

Answer (score 2):

One can show that such a map in the question doesn't exist (no need to assume simply-connectedness).
As abx pointed out, any finite map between smooth projective varieties with trivial canonical bundle must be étale.

Let $\chi(X)$ be the topological Euler characteristic of $X$ and $d$ be the degree of the map. Since $X$ is rigid,
$$\chi(X) = 2 \left( h^{1,1}(X)- h^{1,2}(X) \right)  =2  h^{1,1}(X) > 0.$$

Noting $d \cdot \chi(X) = \chi(X)$, one has $d=1$.